# Converting date to string SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am building report in data warehouse which relay on comparing daily checks and payments for one of the restaurants. I need to be able to filter data on date field however it needs to be compared with string that looks like US date format but is string so

```
Select a.* from 
xx a, xy b
where 
a.payment_date = b.check_date
```

Format of a.payment_date is DD-MON-YY(date) and format of b.check_date is MM/DD/YYYY however it is a string. Any pointers to most efficient ways of solving this problem greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you're asking about efficiency, doing `JOIN` with conversion operators _will_ hurt performance in a bad way. The _efficient_ way would be to add a real date column. Sadly, it's seldom the realistic one.

Comment: Where does this string actually come from?

Comment: It is old legacy system that spits out strings rather than dates.

Comment: @Lomo_effect A trigger that converts the inserted string to a new date column on insert/update could be a solution then. It would speed things up when doing `JOIN` for sure, but the work involved may not be worth the speed gain if the query isn't time sensitive.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson what is better : converting string into date and comparing dates or converting date into string and comparing strings ?? I cannot add columns, build triggers or anything like this as I operate on quite large WH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `check_date` from `string` to `date` using [`TO_DATE()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM xx a, xy b
WHERE a.payment_date = TO_DATE(b.check_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Or you can do the other way around, using [`TO_CHAR()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php).

Comment: Thx, Joao it seems quite simple but yet proved to be very effective.

Comment: @Lomo_effect - To compare dates you should always apply TRUNC() in front of dates unless you are trying to compare date and time.

Answer (score 1):

Convert both String dates into real dates (http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) so you can compare them date-wise.

Answer (score 0):

i think this may work fr you

Select a.* from 
xx a, xy b
where 
convert(datetime,a.payment_date) = convert(datetime,b.check_date)

Comment: oracle doesn't use convert.  It uses to_date.